# What is the cost of using a Docker image on GitLab CI/CD jobs?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

What is the cost of using a Docker image on GitLab CI/CD jobs?

Does the Docker image get downloaded every time that the GitLab pipeline runs?

What is the advantage (if any) of using smaller Docker images (e.g. Alpine Linux)?

Comment: SO is intended for "programming questions".  Nevertheless: 1) Consult GitLab for pricing info.  2) You purchase a GitLab subscription.  Each subscription tier provides minimum storage, compute and data transfer.  You only pay extra if you exceed those thresholds. 3) Anything your CI/CD pipeline does - including running Docker containers - will probably use storage, compute and network.  4) And yes: the smaller your Docker container, the better.  See also: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html